# Unable to get the newly created table cell through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am going through a problem that i am creating a html table using jquery and add click event to its table cells. it is working perfectly fine but when i add a new table row in that table then it wont catch the click event on the newly created row. The earler rows are working fine.

I am send u my code your help will be highly appreciated.

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .cpHeader
    {
        color: white;
        background-color: #719DDB;
        font: bold 11px auto "Trebuchet MS", Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:450px;
        height:18px;
        padding: 4px;           
    }
    .cpBody
    {
        background-color: #DCE4F9;
        font: normal 11px auto Verdana, Arial;
        border: 1px gray;               
        width:450px;
        padding: 4px;
        padding-top: 7px;

    } 
    .imageClass
    {
        background-image:url(Images/expand.png);

    }
    .tableCell
    {
       padding: 5px;
    }
     .buttonCSS
     {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:Green;


     }     
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        createTable($("#tbl"), 5, 5);

        $(".tableCell").click(function () {
            alert("Column # = " + $(this).data("col") + "\n Row # = " + $(this).data("row"));

        });

        function createTable(tbody, rows, column) {
            if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                var trow = $("<tr>");
                trow.data("trow", i);
                for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    var celltext = "" + i + "." + j;
                    $("<td>")
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(celltext)
                        .data("col", j + 1)
                        .data("row", i + 1)
                        .appendTo(trow);
                }
                trow.appendTo(tbody);
            }
            $(tbody).data("rows", rows);
            $(tbody).data("cols", column);

        }

        $("#addRowBtn").click(function () {
            var table = $("#tbl");
            var trow = $("<tr>");
            var columns = table.data("cols");
            for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                var td = $("<td>")
                td.addClass("tableCell");
                td.data("col", i + 1)
                td.data("row", table.data("rows") + 1 )
                td.text("" + (table.data("rows") + 1) + "." + (i + 1))
                td.appendTo(trow);
            }
            trow.appendTo(table);
            table.data("rows", table.data("rows") + 1);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function to bind your event handlers here.

```
$('#tbl').delegate('.tableCell', 'click', function(){
    alert("Column # = " + $(this).data("col") + "\n Row # = " + $(this).data("row"));
});
```

This will catch all clicks on `.tableCell`s that are children of `#tbl`, even if the `.tableCell` elements do not exist at the time which `delegate` is called.

**Here's a simple demo demonstrating this live: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/hBkKh/**

Comment: Thanx alot but a little confusion is that, why should i have to add delegate for the newly created cells when the earlier cells are working even without setting the delegate?

Comment: @Abdul You don't, you should use this *instead* of the click event handler - this will work for your existing cells too. If you want a detailed explanation on how the difference between `delegate` and `bind`, you can look at the documentation I've linked to in the answer, or search around for the excellent explanations provided by those who are more experienced than me here on SO